# Can't create one to many relationship between AspNetUsers and Custom Table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I am trying to build one to many relationship between AspnetUsers and Trip.
My Trip class is as given below:

```
public class Trip
{
    public int TripId { get; set; }
    public string TripName { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

I have added following in IdentityModel:

```
public virtual ICollection<Trip> Trips {get; set; }
```

Now when I try to run this or update-database I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple object sets per type are not   supported. The object sets 'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain   instances of type 'IdentityRelationship.Models.ApplicationUser'                                            
      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DbSetDiscoveryService.RegisterSets(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModelBuilder()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldInitialCreate(String language, String rootNamespace)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
```

Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type 'IdentityRelationship.Models.ApplicationUser'.

Can anyone please tell me what's going on and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion class called `Trip`, should contains IdentityModel's  foreign key virtual property (navigation property).

Fore example:

```
public class Trip{

public int TripId { get; set; }
public string TripName { get; set; }
public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

public int IdentityModelId{ get; set; }

[ForeignKey("IdentityModelId")]
public virtual IdentityModel IdentityModel{get; set; }
}
```

And afther that it should be possible to populate the collection into Trips property at IdentityModel class.